# Bug with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

The MWE below is producing the errors

> ! Package tikz-cd Error: Arrow direction argument must contain only
>   the characters u, d, l, r.
>
> l.7   A \arrow[r] &
>                       B
>
> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/r' and I am
>   going to igno re it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

I'm using (updated today)

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.7.14)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[r] & B
 \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works with miktex.

Comment: @HarishKumar, what is your version of `tikz-cd` package? I have *Version 0.9b, of March 8, 2014*.

Comment: `tikz-cd.sty    2014/03/08 v0.9b Commutative diagrams with tikz` ;) http://i.stack.imgur.com/GgVEb.png

Comment: @HarishKumar, strange. `texless tikz-cd` returned *\ProvidesPackage{tikz-cd}[2012/12/30 v0.3c Commutative diagrams with tikz.]*.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I found the problem. I don't why but somebody saved a `tikz-cd.sty` old file on my home folder. I deleted it and now I'm loading the updated one. Thanks. I'll delete my post soon.